# How to link static image asset from SXA using scriban

Tags: scriban

Sorry this is probably a dumb question but I can't seem to find anything related to it in google.

Basically, I have a static image asset in my SXA Extension theme.
e.g

```
/sitecore/media library/Extension Themes/My Extension/static/images/hero-image
```

I want to call it directly in a Scriban template and thought that may be using a code like this will suffice

```
 <img src="/static/images/hero-image.jpg" alt="">
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas will be hugely appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using full media path? `<img src="/-/media/extension-themes/my-extension/static/images/hero-image.jpg"`

Comment: This one works but I kinda hesitate with this approach because what if user needs to rename the Extension-Themes. :( What I've done instead is just added it to static folder in my VS Solution and just use /static

Answer (score 1):

You probably resolved this already - but just in case you still have it hard coded and want to fix it.

Use the `sc_query` function to retrieve your image using the Sitecore `ID` of the media item.

The `sc_query` function returns an array - but we don't care if we only have one item in the array.

Then use the `sc_field` function to render the image or use the img tag and set the `src` attribute.

```
{{ for i_mediaitem in (sc_query i_home 'query:./*[@@id={ID of media item]') }}
    <img src="{{i_mediaitem.media_url}}">
{{end}}
```

The syntax of the query will need some work, but once the value is retrieved you won't have the path hard coded anymore, just the media item's id.